# How to combine JSON data from multiple API's using NodeJS server

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS server that takes data from three different API's, and then sends the JSON from the three API's to my front end. Since I labeled the data from the three API's differently, it gets sent in three different arrays??(wrong term here maybe?). I'm trying to send it all in one array if possible!

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

router.get("/", function(req, res){
var request = require('request-promise');
var data1;
var data2;
var data3;


request("http://api1.com").then(function(body){
data1 = JSON.parse(body);

return request("http://api2.com");
})
.then(function(body) {
    data2 = JSON.parse(body);


    return request("http://api3.com");
})
.then(function(body){
    data3 = JSON.parse(body);

    res.json("services.ejs", {data1: data1, data2: data2, data3: data3});
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Result:

```
{"data1":[{All JSON from API #1}] - "Data2":[{All JSON from API #2}] - "Data3":[{All JSON from API #3}]}
```

Wanted Result:

`{"allData": [{All JSON from API #1 #2 #3}]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the 3 different results together into one array:

```
var alldata = data1.concat(data2).concat(data3);
res.json("services.ejs", {data: alldata});
```

Adjust accordingly, depending on exactly what you want in the results.